# How do I determine if a negative float is between two other negative numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why is it that if I do

```
-102.between?(-100,-105)
```

in Ruby, it returns false?

-102 is indeed between -100 and -105, correct?

I'm trying to do this with a longitude coordinate (which in my hemisphere will be negative) so for example if:

```
ilong = -102.560
if ilong.between?(-100.000,-105.000) then utmzone = 10 end
puts utmzone
```

should return 10.

How do I accomplish this?

-Jim

Comment: +1 didn't know about this method before. Obviously you haven't ever been a PHP programmer, because the first thing you'd have tried was reversing the argument order! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

-102 is between -100 and -105 but, the order you're specifying is backwards as -105 < -100 try:

```
-102.between?(-105, -100)
```

Comment: PERFECT. I had no luck finding any sort of reference to this on Google or in any of my Ruby books (O'reilly and Apress). It makes sense of course...

Comment: @Jim Wharton: For future reference, if it's a non-Rails method, try searching ruby-doc.org or APIdock (if it's not down). Here's the RDoc link: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html#M001370